# How do I cable up a 10kw generator to my house from garage?

Tags: electrical

I have an 8kw propane or 10kw gas generator in the back of the garage. It has a 50 amp hook up so I have run 6/3 w/g wire to a weatherhead. I have the hook up for the 6/3 w/g service cable. Now, I am looking at running the service to the house & straight down the wall to a junction box in the basement.

The question is do I have to cut the service cable at the house or is there something like Chinese fingers to wrap it at the house, then go down, or run a steel cable from the garage to the house? What do I use to hold up the service cable on the steel wire?

Comment: That's a lot of questions, and some of them seem to have flawed assumptions about how generators are integrated with home services. Please revise to simplify and clarify what you need to know. Take the [tour] and see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to learn what good questions look like.

Comment: From what I have seen, cable is wrapped around steel cable.  You do know that running generator inside kills people.  How far is garage to house?  Have you thought of running cable underground?

Comment: What make and model is your generator, and I take it your "service cable" has 3 insulated wires wrapped around a bare wire? Also, how far is the garage from the house, how is electric power provided *to* the garage, and is there a reason you're not considering burying the wiring instead?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong words when you say "service cable".  Service cable is the wires between the utility and the meter.  After that, it's feeder.  You may mean "overhead line wire".

Answer (score 1):

Edit. I may have mis read so the second half is about tie in this first part is support of a cable: thanks @Izzy +

If talking about a cable grip like a U eye weave split lace.
these provide support to a cable like those finger locks but they wrap around and are laced together.
There are weaves that are not split but then you have to feed the length of cable from to the point of support .

one of my small ones is an L9575  1-1/4-1-1/2” cable size get ready for some sticker shock these run 60-70$ and the larger size I use is ~$130. But they do support the cable if this is the question.

To tie a generator into your home power system there are 2 ways to do it.

The least expensive is a mechanical interlock kit that locks the main circuit breaker in the off position then allows a breaker to be turned on (yes with the main off) back feeding a breaker from the generator to power circuits that are turned on (some will need to be turned off or you will overload your generator.

The other method transfer switches has 2 sub categories.
A whole house transfer switch is a large “double or triple pole double throw” switch. The utility power is connected on one side and the generator is on the other. The house panel is the common so in 1 position the panel is connected to the utility flip the switch and the panel is connected to the generator )some breakers in the main need to be turned off to prevent overloading the generator.

The second transfer switch method is you choose the circuits to connect to the generator.
Each circuit is a switch that connects single or double pole double throw. These circuits are re-wired to a separate switch box unit that only powers the circuits wanted so you don’t overload the generator each switch is usually moved to the utility or generator position this is the most fool proof but also the most expensive method and it limits what can be powered.

The interlock or transfer switch methods prevent you from back feeding onto the power lines where the voltage man transformed to 12kv up to 35kv depending if in the city or country. That high voltage can kill a lineman or someone messing with down lines that were not hot a second before, but more likely is the massive load on your generator as you just became the power company will overload your generator and hopefully trip it’s breakers if not it will smoke the alternator and your generator is toast.

Answer (score 1):

The normal thing to do is use "overhead service drop cable" such as [4-4-4-4 Hackney](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/4-4-4-4-hackney-aluminum-quadruplex-acsr-overhead-service-drop-cable) (you can use smaller, but this will have similar voltage drop to #6 Cu).  You need 4 conductors because you must handle neutral and ground separately.

In this cable, the *bare* wire is the physical carrier wire, which carries the weight of the other conductors.   That bare wire is attached to a physical anchor that is built into the building, designed to bear the tension of the wire (which is considerable - it's not just the weight of the wire, it's catenary forces too, plus dynamic forces from the wind whipping it).

If the weatherhead is stoutly built, the anchor can be a "service drop attachment" which clamps to the weatherhead within 12" of the top.

I have also seen anchors separately set into the roof of the building.

---

Almost any service drop cable on the market will be aluminum.  So are *most* service entrance wires (i.e. the wire going up the weatherhead pipe).  So most bonds up there are aluminum-aluminum.  Yours will be aluminum-copper. Dissimilar metal bonds aren't normally a problem, but that one will live in the great outdoors. Keep an eye on it.